# python-oauth2 - issue Request objects

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0

Via the tutorial at https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2, I can create a signed Request object. But I don't understand how to send the request and receive anything back.

When I check the URL that I get from request.to_url(), I get a response. I just don't know how to get it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a GET request, you can just do

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(request.to_url())
response_body = response.read()    # in case you need it
```

For POST, you should be able to do

```
import urllib2
urllib2_req = urllib2.Request(request.url, request.to_postdata())
response = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2_req)
response_body = response.read()    # in case you need it
```